# Where are factory default setting stored in a wireless module?

Tags: wireless, configuration

In almost all devices we find "Restore To default factory settings" option available. If factory settings are done all the data in the device is erased. So where are these factory setting details stored?

In specific, if anyone could explain where and how are these options stored in a wireless bridge which we use in home and office.

1) Say I do not make any changes to these default setting and use them in my application. How are these settings retrieved and applied when the device is switched on back after reset?

2) Secondly, if I make some changes to the configuration settings, where are these settings stored and retrieved back after the module reset.

Comment: For Every product there are different types of Memories. In most, Defualt configuration is stored in ROM. Changed configurations are stored in memories like Flash/EEPROM

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused by the somewhat misleading phrase "all the data in the device". The manuals use this phrase to denote the data that you, as user, can change. This data is often a copy of a set of data that is "permanently" stored in the device by the factory. It is only a (very) small subset of the total (non-volatile) data in the device.

In most modern devices (semi) permanent data (and also code!) is stored in FLASH or EEPROM memory (both terms refer to variations of the same technique). Such memory can be written by the device, but it is often programmed not to do so for most of its memory: only the user-changeable part is written.

Answer (score 1):

Most computer-on-chip based products have only a tiny bit of true ROM, which stores a bootloader that loads the main program from semi-permanent, but upgradeable memory such as flash chip of several megabytes capacity.

Trivially modifiable but non-volatile configuration would typically be stored in EEPROM, though storage in a designated block of the flash is possible too.  Unsaved working settings would be in RAM.

It is likely that a reset to factory settings would copy a block of data compiled into the program itself over the top of the user-modifiable settings.  Alternatively the settings could come from a reserved block of memory.  If the system runs with a filesystem image, they could even come from a default settings "file".  (It is common for such filesystem images to be read only - often they are stored in compressed form in flash with a working copy uncompressed to RAM during boot - however writeable filesystems are found on some systems, and so it is possible that the current user configuration could be stored within a current settings file)